Unable to read multiple Timeline events from Flutter DevTools WS
I am trying to use the ws to monitor performance of a little test app, but I am not getting the expected events.
First of all, in my local Flutter SDK:
/// When this flag is set to true, timeline events will be recorded for each
/// post-frame callback that runs
bool debugTracePostFrameCallbacks = true;

The Widgets being monitored can be found in here, and they all use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback, since its implementation provides Timeline tracking out of the box:

  /// In debug mode, if [debugTracePostFrameCallbacks] is set to true, then the
  /// registered callback will show up in the timeline events chart, which can
  /// be viewed in [DevTools](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools).
  /// In that case, the `debugLabel` argument specifies the name of the callback
  /// as it will appear in the timeline. In profile and release builds,
  /// post-frame are never traced, and the `debugLabel` argument is ignored.

void addPostFrameCallback(FrameCallback callback, {String debugLabel = 'callback'}) {
    assert(() {
      if (debugTracePostFrameCallbacks) {
        final FrameCallback originalCallback = callback;
        callback = (Duration timeStamp) {
          Timeline.startSync(debugLabel);
          try {
            originalCallback(timeStamp);
          } finally {
            Timeline.finishSync();
          }
        };
      }
      return true;
    }());
    _postFrameCallbacks.add(callback);
  }

Now, here  you will find the connection to the ws, and the list of messages sent to listen to Timeline events.
The app is run in debug mode, as suggested by addPostFrameCallback.
The problem is, I only seem to be receiving events for one label at a time ("Inherited", most likely because it's the first widget to be registered in app).
Before opening this issue I have spent days searching for an answer online, on Discord, direclty from the Dart VM, etc etc. What is the best way to fix this?
